# What is the difference between Ejected Expo App and React Native CLI App?

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, expo

I built an App with Expo but I have to convert it to React Native CLI. I think I have two options now.

- First, ejecting the current Expo app.
- Second, creating a React Native CLI project, installing all dependencies of the expo app and configure it for Android & iOS and copy the files.

I already ejected the current expo app and its structure looks quite similar to React Native CLI. I am new to React Native world and can't decide.

Is the second option necessary to do if I need a React Native CLI base? Or ejected expo app is React Native CLI already. What confused me is that ejected expo app still has expo dependencies in it, it sounds to me as if it is half expo app or something.

```
  "dependencies": {
    "expo": "~42.0.0",
    "expo-linear-gradient": "~9.2.0",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.11.2",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.0.4",
    "expo-updates": "~0.8.1",
    // ...
  }
```

If it is already React Native CLI, why there're `expo` dependencies still in `package.json` or I can safely remove them.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: there is no difference. you could approach it from the other direction and initialize a project with @react-native-community/cli and then add these dependencies to it (https://docs.expo.dev/bare/hello-world/). expo modules are react-native modules and can be used in any react-native app.

Comment: 1. Why you eject the app, is this really necessary ?
2. You can use expo libraries in a react native app too, so if you use the functionality depending on packages in your package.json you should keep them.